# Filtering using LINQ.Dynamic over Null properties throw an exception

Tags: linq, exception, filter

I am using Linq.Dynamic, I have a List of Tier(string Matricule,string Nom..) although some Tiers have no Matricule, but when run the LINQ where over the Matricule property, System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object is throwed?
here is the detail of the code:

```
public class Tier
{
    public string Matricule{get;set;}
    public string Nom{get;set;}
    public string Prenom{get;set;}
}

public class FilterByPredicate
    {
        public BindingList<T> Filter(string propName,string propValue,bool fromFirst)
            {

                var predicateString = fromFirst
                                ? "{0}.ToString().ToUpper().StartsWith(@{1})"
                                : "{0}ToString().ToUpper().Contains(@{1})";

                return new BindingList<T>(_list.Where(string.Format(predicateString, propName, 0), propValue.ToUpper()).ToList());
            }

     }


in other part of my code i call..
    FilterByPredicate fbp = new FilterByPredicate(costumersList>);
    textBox1_Changed+=
    { 
       tiersBindingSource.DataSource =fbp .Filter("Matricule", textBox1.Text,true);// exception throwed

//but this work fine-> var q = from c in costumersList where c.Matricule.ToUpper().StartsWith(textBox1.Text) select c;
    };
```

Comment: Did you read [ask]? Do you understand what MCVE is? (If not, read that *carefully* before asking questions)

Comment: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Your English is fine. Your question is *not*

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution after read the docs, corresponding to "Get started" page, simply compare to null like that:

```
 public BindingList<T> Filter(string propName,string propValue,bool fromFirst)
            {

                var predicateString = fromFirst
                                ? "{0} != null and {0}.ToString().ToUpper().StartsWith(@{1})"
                                : "{0} != null and {0}.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(@{1})";

                return new BindingList<T>(_list.Where(string.Format(predicateString, propName, 0), propValue.ToUpper()).ToList());
            }
```